# Login system in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, logging

I want to create a login system with a MS Access database. the data to log in is in the database.

There is a possibility of working online, you then fill in the login details. And press OK to move to the next screen.

And an ability to work offline, then you put "student" at username (leave password empty) and press OK to move to the next screen.

There must be an error given  if the credentials are wrong but there should be no error when only "student" is filled

Now the problem is it gives the error as a "student" is entered here, but he should not error to give. Only when the login data is wrong. How do I fix this?

Code:

```
/**Local*/
    try {
         String idnr = GebruikersnaamTekst.getText().trim();
         if (idnr.matches("Cursist")) {
        BasisScherm b = new BasisScherm();
            b.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);   
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

/**Internet*/
  try

   {

    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    st = con.createStatement();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

  }

   try
        {

        String idnr = GebruikersnaamTekst.getText().trim();
        String pass = Password.getText().trim();

        String sql = "select idnr,pass from Table1 where idnr='"+idnr+"'and pass='"+pass+"'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

           int count = 0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

          if (count == 1) {
        BasisScherm b = new BasisScherm();
            b.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);   
        }

        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gebruiker niet gevonden!");
        }

        }
        catch(Exception ex )
        { 
        }




}
```

Comment: We can't tell you without seeing the code...

Comment: Could we see some of the code you're working on? That will help quite a bit to help with an answer.

Comment: I doubt anyone will help you without seeing some code first!

Comment: its better to have a test case for login operation or just execute the select with provided value check if it return any record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for it to succeed if you match correctly for "Student" right?

It might be an issue of case sensitivity, try this.

```
if (idnr.toLowerCase().matches("cursist"))
```

That will evaluate true, and be case insensitive.

Also as far as program flow goes, if those are in the same class, or main() function, it will execute the Internet regardless of the local outcome, which could also introduce errors.

Create a global Boolean variable perhaps. To confirm that you've done the student check/
Full code:

```
/**Local*/
boolean isStudent = false;
    try {
         String idnr = GebruikersnaamTekst.getText().trim();
         if (idnr.matches("Cursist")) {
        BasisScherm b = new BasisScherm();
            b.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);   
            isStudent=true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
if(!isStudent)
{
/**Internet*/
  try

   {

    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
    st = con.createStatement();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

  }

   try
        {

        String idnr = GebruikersnaamTekst.getText().trim();
        String pass = Password.getText().trim();

        String sql = "select idnr,pass from Table1 where idnr='"+idnr+"'and pass='"+pass+"'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

           int count = 0;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

          if (count == 1) {
        BasisScherm b = new BasisScherm();
            b.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);   
        }

        else 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gebruiker niet gevonden!");
        }

        }
        catch(Exception ex )
        { 
        }

}  }//end if
```

Comment: GebruikersnaamTekst is a JJtekstfield and if this matches "cursist" and you press on ok button  he will move to next screen. But the else statement "Gebruiker niet gevonden" must not shown up when the data is correct filled in en when "cursist" is filled in

Comment: Right, I understand the logic, I think. What I'm seeing is, it will add the button, then execute the SQL call regardless, therefore also outputting the error. I'll add more to the answer…

Comment: Sorry got another question, is it possible when "Student" is filled in at GebruikersnaamTekst (tekstfield) to disable the password field so u cant put anything in it?

Comment: What kind of window is this operating in? I'm a little inexperienced with Java UI construction, but I would think you could add in an event handler to the GebruikersnaamTekst to make the Password.setVisible(false),

Comment: The code is now:

  try {
             String idnr = GebruikersnaamTekst.getText();
            if (idnr.matches("Cursist")) {
                Password.setEditable(false);
            } else {
                Password.setEditable(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

but didn't work, it's only not need to edit when GebruikersnaamTekst is "student"

Comment: I see JOptionPane which is part of the Swing library, but past that I'm not super clear on how to work in the UI part of Java. Where's the code that renders all the items on screen?